# What will the order of slot execution if two signals are emitted at the same time in same thread?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am trying to understand the code of HMI (QT based application).
Typically in a embedded software, multiple ECUs send data at the same time to the UI.

In which order 2 different slots (2 different UI classes) connected to 2 different signals, be executed if both the signals are triggered at same time within the same thread?

Are they being executed in parallel ? (I guess not possible since there is only 1 thread in picture)

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for two signals to be fired at the same time from a single thread

Comment: @rustyx 
In the given link, he is emitting signals by himself. Hence it will always be serialized.
But in my case I dont have control over the signal emission code. It is from some lower layer  of applciation.

Comment: @perivesta
If that is the case, then it could be the answer.
Maybe the lower layer code is taking care of signal emission

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum if your slot is in the same thread it is executed immediately. If not, it will be queued. Unless you specified different connection type by hand. And if you emit 2 signals from 1 thread, there is no such thing as "at the same time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI classes should be typically handled in your main thread and only heavy computation that can block the UI in worker threads.

So, by default, you would get them executed subsequently, and cannot certainly be in parallel in an ideal design.

Yes, you are right, there is no parallelism with a single thread.

Even with multiple threads involved, you would only ever see true parallelism if the receivers are in different threads.

For further information on various connection types, please refer to the [official Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Comment: If I have a UI class ( A widget shown on screen, listening for events from mouse and keyboards ) and a slot of different UI class ( A widget which is hidden ). Both in same thread.

When the slot of hidden widget  is executed, the the visible UI widget gets blocked (It cannot take mouse/keyboard events). But since the slot is executed so fast, it seems the widget is never blocked.
Is this understanding right ?

Comment: @Avi: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

> In which order 2 different slots (2 different UI classes) connected to
> 2 different signals, be executed **if both the signals are triggered at
> same time within the same thread**?

When two signals are being emitted from the same thread, it is not possible to be emitted simultaneously. So the signals are being emitted one after another.

Order of slots execution is same as order of signals emission, when Qt::DirectConnection is used, or if both the receiver objects are in the same thread as the sender.

It is always recommended not to depend on the order of slot execution.